# innerHTML don't update tags

Tags: javascript, html, function, bootstrap-5, innerhtml

i want to see a icon , if both password are the same. But in my Javascript the inlineHTML don't update next to the label tag.

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc4Eh.png)
[JavaScript Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wzQa.png)

I tried in diffrent ways, but it is not reflect on browser and i don't have an error or something else.

Comment: Please add an example on JsFiddle or similar site or directly add the code to your question instead of using image

Comment: @vicnoob Please don't ask for jsfiddle when a stack snippet will work fine.

Comment: There's no `id="PasswortCheck"` in the HTML.

Comment: @Barmar Where is the stack snippet?

Comment: @vicnoob https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection. You need to index it to change a particular element.

Comment: @Barmar He doesn't have the code snippet, it's what I'm asking for

Comment: @vicnoob I know, I'm just suggesting that you ask for it as a stack snippet, not jsfiddle or other site. I thought you didn't know what a stack snippet is.